# What happens in Utah, if no candidate gets more than 50% of the vote?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college, utah

In Utah (and most states) the winning candidate gets all delegates. Generally, a candidate must get more than 50% of the vote in order to win an election. But in the case of a multi-party race, what happens if there is a three-way split? Does the candidate with the most votes take all?

Comment: Do you mind putting that "generally" in a cultural context? Plurality voting/ first past the post is by no means uncommon, even in the USA.

Comment: A majority vote requirement is very uncommon in the U.S. in federal elections. A couple of states (most notably Louisiana) have it, but the lion's share of states require a mere plurality to win.

Comment: I guess I was thinking about how the voting worked at the county convention and assumed it was that way in a general election.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Under Utah election law (specifically Title 20A, Chapter 13, Part 3, Section 301(2) of the Utah Code),

> The highest number of votes cast for a political party's president and vice president candidates elects the presidential electors selected by that political party.

A majority is not required.